# Erro ao instalar os pacotes do R no CI do GitLab

Tags: r, gitlab

Quando tento instalar os pacotes do R usando o `shell`, acontece o seguinte erro:

Meu código do arquivo `gitlab-ci.yml` esta da seguinte maneira:

```
before_script:
- export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= ----
- pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
script:
  - R -e 'install.packages(c("raster", "rgdal"))'
  - R CMD build . --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
  - PKG_FILE_NAME=$(ls -1t *.tar.gz | head -n 1)
  - R CMD check "${PKG_FILE_NAME}" --no-build-vignettes --no-manual
  - pep8 --show-source --show-pep8 setup.py planex tests
  - nosetests
```

> Warning in install.packages(c("raster", "rgdal")) :
>
> 'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
>
> Error in install.packages(c("raster", "rgdal")) :
>
> unable to install packages
>
> Execution halted
>
> ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1

Comment: você tem permissão para escrever neste diretório? `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`

Comment: drwxrwsr -x 2 root staff 4096 Out5 /usr/local/lib/R/site-libary

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, é o gitlab hosteado ou o gitlab.org?

Answer (score 1):

Ao tentar rodar a parte do `R` do código que você compartilhou (abaixo), obtive um erro de sintaxe. Isso acontece porque nos arquivos `*.yml` a indentação é importante. O *job* sequer começou.

```
test:
script:
  - R -e 'install.packages(c("raster", "rgdal"))’
```

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:test config can't be blank

Ao corrigir o problema com a identação o *job* roda, mas não encontra o `R` e falha.

```
test:
  script:
    - R -e 'install.packages(c("raster", "rgdal"))'
```

> /bin/bash: line 62: R: command not found

Por fim, ao adicionar a imagem do docker do `R` (r-base), a instalação dos pacotes correu sem problemas.

```
test:
  image: rocker/r-base
  script:
    - R -e 'install.packages(c("raster", "rgdal"))'
```

Para uma lista com as várias imagens do `R` no docker, veja [este endereço](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/).

O histórico das builds feitas para esta resposta [pode ser visto aqui](https://gitlab.com/tomasbarcellos/gitlab_teste/pipelines).